# PHP Yii MongoDB in string query

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

I need to find all schools with contains a certain emailaddress in a string

At this moment, I'm sending a query to my database to obtain a list of Schools like this

```
$aSchools = School::model()->findAllByAttributes(array(
    'finished' => School::SCHOOL_CREATED,
));
```

After that, I itterate over all the schools to check if they containt the mailAddress like this:

```
$aFoundSChools = array();
    foreach($aSchools as $oSchool)
    {
        if (strpos($oSchool->mailAddress, Yii::app()->user->mailAddress))
        {
            $aFoundSChools [] = $oSchool;
        }
    }
```

But I'm guessing this could be cleaner, right? Can i do that in a single function, like a 'LIKE' query in sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB supports "like" queries in the form of regular expressions. Be warned though that this can not use an index. From plain PHP, you'd construct it like this:

```
$query = array(
    'finished' => School::SCHOOL_CREATED,
    'mailAddress' => new MongoRegexp( '/' . addslashes( Yii::app()->user->mailAddress ) . '/' ),
);
```

You'll have to use the addslashes if you think your mail address might contain a `/`.

I don't quite know Yii, but I expect you can use `$query` like this, just replacing your already existing test for just 'finished':

```
$aSchools = School::model()->findAllByAttributes( $query );
```